# Jenkinsfile: Are sh subshells permitted?

Tags: maven, jenkins, sh

I have shell script wherein multiple maven command lines are executed concurrently through subshells:

```
# Block 1
(mvn test -Dtest=...
exit)

# Block 2
(mvn test -Dtest=...
exit)

.
.
.
```

Which runs fine when I execute the script file containing these commands -- i.e. - the commands are run concurrently.  However, when I enter it into our build jenkinsfile, the mvn commands appear to be run sequentially.  Is there a way to configure Jenkins to support sh subshells?

Thanks

Comment: This would not run the jobs concurrently unless you put each subshell in the background with `&`.

Comment: That fixed it, thanks!  Not sure how I didn't notice that my shell script NEVER ran the commands synchronously, but that's exactly what was happening.